# React Events not firing inside Fancybox

Tags: reactjs, fancybox

I am trying to use Fancybox in a React component. Although the fancybox is working fine, any events inside are not working. I suspect the cause for this behaviour is that Fancybox creates a new element at the bottom of the page and discards the attached events but I might be wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.esm.js";
import "@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button data-fancybox data-src={`#fancybox`}>Open Fancybox</button><br/>
      <div id="fancybox" style={{display: 'none'}}>
        {/* Doesn't work */}
        <input type="text" onChange={() => {console.log("Test")}} />
        <button onClick={() => {console.log("Test2")}}>Click me</button>
      </div>
      {/* works */}
      <input type="text" onChange={() => {console.log("Test")}} />
      <button onClick={() => {console.log("Test2")}}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to make it work?